# how do I get my text to go next too, and then under my button?

Tags: html, css

I want the text in my second `<textarea>` tag to start at the same line as my copy button and then as my text reaches the copy button, I want my text to go to the next line and on that next line(and every line after that) want it to go fully under my button. I hope I have explained this ok, thank you for taking the time to read this, my code is below.

```js
function myFunction(){
    var text = document.getElementById('input').value;
    var textArray = text.split(" ").sort();
    var output= document.getElementById('output');
    output.value = textArray.toString().replace(/,/g," ");
}

 function maFunction() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("output");
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
    document.execCommand("copy");
}
/*
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
// minified version is also included
// import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.min.css';

class App extends Component {
  notify = () => toast("Wow so easy !");

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.notify}>Notify !</button>
        <ToastContainer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
*/

/*import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

class Example extends Component {
  notify = () => {
    toast("I cannot be duplicated !", {
      toastId: 13
    });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.notify}>Notify</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}*/

function fadeOut(){
   location.href='index.html#open-modal';
   setTimeout(function () {
       location.href='index.html#modal-close';
       }, 1000);
}
```

```css
body {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: flex;
}

.txt {
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #4CAF50;
    border-width: 2px;
    outline: none;
    height: 700px;
    width: 45%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    /*box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);*/
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.text {
    border: none;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    height: 660px;
    width: 630px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    resize: none;
}

.asci {
    background: #ffffff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #4CAF50;
    outline: none;
    height: 700px;
    width: 45%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    /*box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);*/
}

.alpha {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 660px;
    width: 550px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    resize: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: none;
}

.button {
    background: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 14px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 0 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

::selection {
  color: black;
  background: lightblue;
}

.modal-window {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75);
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.modal-window:target {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modal-window > div {
    width: 170px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    /*margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 2rem;*/
    background: #444;
    color: #fff;
}

.modal-window h1 {
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>alphabetical order machine</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form class="txt">
        <textarea class="text"  id="input" type="text" placeholder="type your text here" onchange="myFunction()" onkeyup="myFunction()"></textarea>        
    </form>
    <form class="asci">
        <textarea class="alpha" id="output" readonly="readonly" type="output" placeholder="your alphabetized text will appear here"></textarea>
        <input class="button" type='button' value="copy" onclick="maFunction(),fadeOut()">
    </form>

<div id="open-modal" class="modal-window">
    <div>
        <h1>text copied to clipboard</h1>
        <div></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got what you want correctly, I think here is a better implementation and would solve the text width and alignment, I used [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) CSS and [justify-items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-items) to align elements inside the grid.

---

**NOTE**: I revamped the HTML to make sure that CSS selectors a bit generic

---

```js
function myFunction(){
    var text = document.getElementById('input').value;
    var textArray = text.split(" ").sort();
    var output= document.getElementById('output');
    output.value = textArray.toString().replace(/,/g," ");
}

 function maFunction() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("output");
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
    document.execCommand("copy");
}
/*
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
// minified version is also included
// import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.min.css';

class App extends Component {
  notify = () => toast("Wow so easy !");

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.notify}>Notify !</button>
        <ToastContainer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
*/

/*import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

class Example extends Component {
  notify = () => {
    toast("I cannot be duplicated !", {
      toastId: 13
    });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.notify}>Notify</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}*/

function fadeOut(){
   location.href='index.html#open-modal';
   setTimeout(function () {
       location.href='index.html#modal-close';
       }, 1000);
}
```

```css
body {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: flex;
}

.form {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    column-gap: 10px;
    row-gap: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    justify-items: end;
    postiion: relative;
    
}

.form textarea {
    border: none;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 660px;
    width: 90%;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    resize: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #4CAF50;
    border-width: 2px;
    outline: none;
    height: 700px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.button {
    background: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 14px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 0 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
}

::selection {
  color: black;
  background: lightblue;
}

.modal-window {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75);
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.modal-window:target {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modal-window > div {
    width: 170px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    /*margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 2rem;*/
    background: #444;
    color: #fff;
}

.modal-window h1 {
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>alphabetical order machine</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <form class="form">
        <input class="button" type='button' value="copy" onclick="maFunction(),fadeOut()">
        <textarea class="text"  id="input" type="text" placeholder="type your text here" onchange="myFunction()" onkeyup="myFunction()"></textarea>
        
        <textarea class="alpha" id="output" readonly="readonly" type="output" placeholder="your alphabetized text will appear here"></textarea>
    </form>

<div id="open-modal" class="modal-window">
    <div>
        <h1>text copied to clipboard</h1>
        <div></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**UPDATE**: I fixed the UI for your code in the following snippet, also in the one above, I suggest that you use the one above since its responsive too, but if you want to keep using your code here is a snippet:

---

```js
function myFunction(){
    var text = document.getElementById('input').value;
    var textArray = text.split(" ").sort();
    var output= document.getElementById('output');
    output.value = textArray.toString().replace(/,/g," ");
}

 function maFunction() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("output");
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
    document.execCommand("copy");
}
/*
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
// minified version is also included
// import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.min.css';

class App extends Component {
  notify = () => toast("Wow so easy !");

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.notify}>Notify !</button>
        <ToastContainer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
*/

/*import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

class Example extends Component {
  notify = () => {
    toast("I cannot be duplicated !", {
      toastId: 13
    });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.notify}>Notify</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}*/

function fadeOut(){
   location.href='index.html#open-modal';
   setTimeout(function () {
       location.href='index.html#modal-close';
       }, 1000);
}
```

```css
body {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: flex;
}

.txt {
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #4CAF50;
    border-width: 2px;
    outline: none;
    height: 700px;
    width: 45%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    /*box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);*/
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.text {
    border: none;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    height: 660px;
    width: 630px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    resize: none;
}

.asci {
    background: #ffffff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #4CAF50;
    outline: none;
    height: 700px;
    width: 45%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    /*box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);*/
    position: relative;
}

.alpha {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 660px;
    width: 686px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    resize: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: none;
}

.button {
    background: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 14px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 0 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 48px;
}

::selection {
  color: black;
  background: lightblue;
}

.modal-window {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75);
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.modal-window:target {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modal-window > div {
    width: 170px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    /*margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 2rem;*/
    background: #444;
    color: #fff;
}

.modal-window h1 {
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>alphabetical order machine</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form class="txt">
        <textarea class="text"  id="input" type="text" placeholder="type your text here" onchange="myFunction()" onkeyup="myFunction()"></textarea>        
    </form>
    <form class="asci">
        <textarea class="alpha" id="output" readonly="readonly" type="output" placeholder="your alphabetized text will appear here"></textarea>
        <input class="button" type='button' value="copy" onclick="maFunction(),fadeOut()">
    </form>

<div id="open-modal" class="modal-window">
    <div>
        <h1>text copied to clipboard</h1>
        <div></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thats not what I meant but looking back on it i didnt explain what i meant very well

Comment: @ripjuce, if you explain it, I will fix my answer! just edit your question and add more details to explain the issue, thanks

Comment: I rephrased the question, thank you so much for being understanding :)

Comment: I updated my answer, I hope I got it this time, also note that I used your code, but also fixed the implementation in my implementation, I really suggest that you use the one I enhanced since its responsive and adapt a modern HTML/CSS code.

Comment: thank you! I really appreciate it and I will use your code :)

Comment: @ripjuce, glad to help! please if you find it useful to you accept it as [accept it as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)